# Join two child-nodes with FirebaseDatabase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-structures

I getting started with Firebase Realtime Database and I have a question about my data structure.
See below my current database :

[image]

I've ordered my devices with a OS child, in order to filter by OS and only get the wanted child.

But before filter, I'd like to fill my RecyclerView with all children merged together.

- MacBook Pro
- Mac Pro
- iPhone XS

If I do `FirebaseDatabase.getReference(DEVICES)` I have all the data but not matching my Java Object. 
If I do `FirebaseDatabase.getReference(DEVICES).child(macOS)`, it work, but I have only macOS devices in my list.

Is there any way to "join"

```
FirebaseDatabase.getReference(DEVICES).child(macOS)
FirebaseDatabase.getReference(DEVICES).child(iOS)
...
```

in a single DatabaseReference ?

Moreover, I use Firebase UI in order to bind data to my RecyclerView

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    devices = FishApp.getDatabase().getReference(Constants.DEVICES);
    devices.keepSynced(true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_devices, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    mAdapter = new FirebaseDeviceAdapter(getActivity(), Device.class, R.layout.item_device, DeviceHolder.class, devices);
    return view;
}
```

EDIT : Added Java Code and DB Screenshot

Comment: What is the expected output after you perform the query?

Comment: I'd like to have a list of devices showing a sample info :
for example : 

- MacBook  500GB
- iPhone X 512GB
- SurfacePro 512GB

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your actual database structure.

Comment: Screenshot added

Comment: I understand now. If you are allowed to change your database structure, check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075124/how-i-can-get-data-of-next-child-and-show-it-in-list-view-from-firebase-realtime/57075293#57075293)** out.

Comment: Looks great !

Testing ASAP 
Thanks

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A fast approach would be to watch/capture the **DEVICES** node and then loop through its children. This way you can access all the children and retrieve the ones you need. Here's an illustration.

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("DEVICES");

db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            // test for null and validity
            if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                // loop through all the immediate children
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    // This gets all the children of the mac node
                    if ("macOS".equals(snapshot.getKey())) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            // Retrieve individual values of the macOS node
                        }
                    }
                    // This gets all the children of the windows node
                    else if ("windows".equals(snapshot.getKey())) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            // Retrieve individual values of the windows node
                        }
                    }
                    // This gets all the children of the iOS node
                    else if ("iOS".equals(snapshot.getKey())) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            // Retrieve individual values of the iOS node
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // handle cancel event
        }
    });
```

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Comment: Thank's for this. I've seen an example like this in Javascript.

However, even if the solution would work, I use Firebase UI to bind my data to RecyclerView (see edit) 
And the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter only take a Query or a DatabaseReference as datasource.

Comment: Oh, I see. This is a bit tricky... A brute approach would be to restructure your entire database but I'm sure there is a better approach. Good luck.